# Yii2 Kartik multiple select list error array_combine()

Tags: php, oop, yii2

i use Kartik select dropDownList with multiple options.

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2
 I can add a few  items in loop but i can't update  the   item's because I  get

https://gyazo.com/fae968ed6f881307652598cf2287a32c

what is wrong ?

my controller action who creates a new item in loop

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new reservation();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        foreach ($_POST['Reservation']['id_place']  as $key=> $item) {


            $model->id_reservation = NULL;
            $model->create_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $model->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            $model->id_place=$item;
            $model->isNewRecord = true;
            $model->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_reservation]);

    } else {
        $model->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,

        ]);
    }
}
```

my update action

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_reservation]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

my View

```
echo $form->field($model, 'id_place')->widget(Select2::classname(), [

    'theme' => Select2::THEME_KRAJEE,

    'language' => 'pl',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select  place',
        'id' => 'rezerwacja',
        'multiple'=>true,

    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,

    ],
])->label("Miejsce:  max (5)"); ?>
```

Comment: I haven't used this widget before, but i found the same error on github: (https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2/issues/39). At first glance you missed the data property in the widget in your view. `$form->field($model, 'id_place')->widget(Select2::classname(), ['data'=>$data, ...])->label("Miejsce:  max (5)");`. $data is array the select option data items ([link](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)). I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yeahh you are  right!!  it's working. I forgot this becaouse i  dynamic load  select  thorug  jquery ;) Now I  set up  empty array   'data'=>[] and it's  working. Thanks mate.